# Mysql SUM function with an IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a little financial program to my self and i got stuck whit this little issue here :)

I'm storing my receipts in two different currency (USD, Euro).
Basically i want to do a SELECT query which will return the summed amount of the receipts in Euro.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(type='euro',amount,amount*value)) FROM receipt
```

What i found out so far that this query above won't go through every line of the table. It's summing the second statement only for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it's summing the second statement only*"?  Can you provide a more concrete example?  Some sample data and output, for example.  Perhaps on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT amount FROM receipt WHERE type='euro') AS euro_amount, SUM(SELECT amount FROM receipt WHERE type='usd') AS usd_amount FROM receipt
```

You can't write sum of a field in if condition, you can try above sub-query if you want to get result using single query

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is utterly incorrect.  `SUM(IF())` is perfectly valid. -1

Comment: eggyal I just said "you can't" from the questions perspective and its may be possible but first we need to see a practical view of his scenario am i right?@eggyal

Comment: Well, to my mind the query that the OP is using should be working fine: see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/206a0/1/0).  *A practical view of his scenario*" may well help to identify why it wasn't working for the OP, but ought not to be strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select 
    (select sum(amount) from receipt where type='euro') +
    (select sum(amount)*value from receipt where type != 'euro')
```

Comment: Beware that this will entirely exclude any `receipt where type is null`.

Comment: @eggyal why do you think type can be null?

Comment: I have only common sense :) I wouldn't make this field nullable.

Comment: Rather depends on one's schema.  I can't speak for the OP.